# Token base authentication url is not returning response

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I am new to AngularJS and Single Page Application in ASP.NET MVC. I am using Web API as service and token based authentication for login.  When I am calling authentication URL as below, it is not returning response and then appears to b null.

```
 var data = {
                grant_type: "password",
                username: userName,
                password: loginPassword
            };

 $http.post("/Token", data)
                 .then(function (response) {
                     alert(JSON.stringify( response.data));
                     return response.data;
                 });
```

However when I am passing data as below, it return the response.

```
 var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + userName + "&password=" + loginPassword;

            $http.post("/Token", data)
                 .then(function (response) {
                     alert(JSON.stringify( response.data));
                     return response.data;
                 });
```

**Question:** What is actually happening both cases that first is not responding at all, while other is responding?

Comment: Did you debug your controller action? You can inspect it and see what it's getting in both cases.

Comment: Because the endpoint is expecting url-form-encoded data, not form data.

Comment: @Breden Green you are right. When implemented failure callback to above function it was giving bad request "unsupported_grant_type".